# Expectation of the product of three normal variables

Tags: normal-distribution, covariance, expected-value

Let $(X_1, X_2, X_3)\sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$ be a three-dimensional random variable where each coordinates are dependent (i.e. $\Sigma$ has non-zero values outside of its diagonal)

I want to know how to compute

1. $E(X_1 X_2^2)$
2. $E(X_1 X_2 X_3)$

Thanks.

**EDIT** : I think I know how to do it.
Using [Isserlis Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem), we know that $E((X_1-\mu_1) (X_2-\mu_2) (X_3-\mu_3))=0$.
Also, using the identity $E(X_i X_j) = E(X_i)E(X_j) + Cov(X_i,X_j)$

I expand the expression $E((X_1-\mu_1) (X_2-\mu_2) (X_3-\mu_3))=0$ and use the covariance identity to get:

$$E(X_1 X_2 X_3)=E(X_1) E(X_2) E(X_3)
+E(X_1)Cov(X_2,X_3)
+E(X_2)Cov(X_1,X_3)
+E(X_3)Cov(X_1,X_2)$$

or put differently
$$E(X_1 X_2 X_3)=\mu_1\mu_2\mu_3
+\mu_1\sigma_{23}
+\mu_2\sigma_{13}
+\mu_3\sigma_{12}$$

To get $E(X_1 X_2^2)$, Can I use the derived result and say that $X_3=X_2$ all the time ? 
I simply replace the "3"s by 2 in the formula to get

$$E(X_1 X_2^2)=E(X_1 X_2 X_2)=\mu_1\mu_2\mu_2
+\mu_1\sigma_{22}
+\mu_2\sigma_{12}
+\mu_2\sigma_{12}
=\mu_1(\mu_2^2
+\sigma_2^2)
+2\mu_2\sigma_{12}
$$

**Can somebody confirm that I am not doing something wrong ?**

Thank you.